# What cable do I need to connect my Mac Mini to a VGA monitor?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, adapter, mini-displayport

Just received my Mac Mini and I'm trying to figure out what cable I need to connect to my VGA monitor.

The monitor only has a VGA connection and in the Mac Mini manual that was in the box, it says that I would need a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adaptor. But as far as I can see my Mac Mini does not have a Mini DisplayPort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Thunderbolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29) standard is a superset of [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) – your Thunderbolt connector *is* a Mini DisplayPort connector.

[image]

Comment: And on a subjective note, you really should buy a newer monitor.  Pretty much anything these days that isn't for some super-specialized purpose has at least ONE digital input on it.

Comment: @slhck - Thanks for the picture, I was actually looking for a decent one but I got pulled away from my desk for a bit. :)

Comment: @slhck Just to understand correct, the picture shows the Mini DisplayPort, right?

Comment: @Muleskinner Exactly. It looks the same as a Thunderbolt port!

Comment: @slhck thanks, only visual difference is the label (thunderbolt having a thunder icon)